# Call pybind11:function with tupled arguments?

Tags: pybind11

In C++, I need to invoke Python functions that can have any number of arguments.

Is it possible to invoke a pybind function object with tupled arguments, similar to `PyObject_CallObject` (https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/call.html#object-calling-api)?

I tried passing tupled arguments with `()` operator and the `.call()` method, but it seems to be expecting the exact arguments instead of tupled argument (`missing 1 required positional argument`).

Comment: It doesn't seem to be supported, probably worth opening a feature request on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks, filed https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/4560.

Answer (score 3):

You can directly unpack Python tuples<sup>1</sup> with pybind11

```cpp
py::function callable = ...;
py::tuple args = ...;
callable(*args);
```

See [unpacking arguments](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/object.html#unpacking-arguments) in pybind11 documentation.

---

Worth noting that if you have a C++ tuple, you can use [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply)

```cpp
py::function callable = ...;
std::tuple<int, int> args = ...;
std::apply(callable, args);
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> You can create a `py::tuple` for heterogeneous variables using `py::make_tuple` or from most standard containers using `py::cast` (if you include the `<pybind11/stl.h>` header).</sub>